# How to choose which JUnit5 Tags to execute with Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

I have just upgraded my solution to use JUnit5. Now trying to create tags for my tests that have two tags: `@Fast` and `@Slow`. To start off I have used the below maven entry to configure which test to run with my default build. This means that when I execute `mvn test` only my fast tests will execute. I assume I can override this using the command line. But I can not figure out what I would enter to run my slow tests....

I assumed something like.... `mvn test -Dmaven.IncludeTags=fast,slow` which does not work

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <includeTags>fast</includeTags>
            <excludeTags>slow</excludeTags>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: it does not work for me either.

My code in githup as below link:
https://github.com/anhtv08/junit5-splitting-test

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use this way:

```
<properties>
    <tests>fast</tests>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>allTests</id>
        <properties>
            <tests>fast,slow</tests>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <groups>${tests}</groups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This way you can start with `mvn -PallTests test` all tests (or even with `mvn -Dtests=fast,slow test`).

Comment: Leaving empty <tests> tag inside allTests profile makes sure all tests are run, even if a new tag is added to the code.

Comment: `<includeTags/>` is not a valid configuration option as far as I can see. Would you mind supplying a documentation reference?

Comment: This answer seems indeed wrong as there is no `<includeTags>` in surefire, it should be `<groups>` or `<excludedGroups>`

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#Filtering_by_Tags

Answer (score 29):

Using a profile is a possibility but it is not mandatory as `groups` and `excludedGroups` are user properties defined in the [maven surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) to respectively include and exclude any JUnit 5 tags (and it also works with JUnit 4 and TestNG test filtering mechanism).
So to execute tests tagged with `slow` or `fast` you can run :

```
mvn test -Dgroups=fast,slow
```

If you want to define the excluded and/or included tags in a Maven profile you don't need to declare a new property to convey them  and to make the association of them in the maven surefire plugin. Just use `groups` and or `excludedGroups` defined and expected by the maven surefire plugin :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>allTests</id>
        <properties>
            <groups>fast,slow</groups>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can omit profile and just use properties, it is more elastic way.

```
<properties>
    <tests>fast</tests>
</properties>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <groups>${tests}</groups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then you can runt fast tests by typing `mvn test`, all test by typing `mvn test -Dtests=fast | slow` or only slow by typing `mvn test -Dtests=slow`. When you have more test tags then you can also run all of them except the selected type by typing `mvn test -Dtests="! contract"`.