# Is there any way to filter out Junit test report ? Just want to publish report only for some test in Jenkins not for all.

Tags: xml, maven, jenkins, junit

There is a requirement in our project where we want to publish JUnit report in Jenkins but not for all test cases,only for some test cases those are following a naming convention.**Note**-:We don't want to skip those test execution,we just don't want to publish those test result in Jenkins.Please let me know if there is a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I would defer the task of distinguishing between tests to your build tool, as both Maven and Gradle have more-or-less native ways of doing this.

In **Maven**, you can use a tool like [Surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) to exclude/include tests based on classname or [JUnit 5+ tags](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering) ([StackOverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421688/how-to-choose-which-junit5-tags-to-execute-with-maven?rq=1)). **Gradle's** Java plugin has classname-based [test filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test), and also supports JUnit 5+ tags.

Once you've created build tasks that distinguish between different test groupings, you can define your Jenkins pipeline stages like so:

```
stage('Unreported Tests') {
    steps {
        sh './gradlew runUnreportedTests'
    }
}
stage('Reported Tests') {
    steps {
        sh './gradlew runReportedTests'
    }
    post {
        always {
            junit 'build/reports/**/*.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using maven and I was going through that Surefire link earlier also. One doubt I have, Does this part <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude> exclude the test execution or exclude the test report to be published.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?