# maven-surefire plugin is not running few of the Junit5 test profiles

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

We've a simple Junit/Junit5 & Maven-surefire based test framework.

We run the tests using following commands:

```
mvn clean test -PlistingGROUP
mvn clean test -PsignUpGROUP
mvn clean test -PloginGROUP
```

The groups are defined under  section of the POM.xml

```
  <profile>
        <id>listingGROUP</id>
        <properties>
            <groups>listingTag</groups>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>loginGROUP</id>
        <properties>
            <groups>loginTag</groups>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>signUpGROUP</id>
        <properties>
            <groups>signUpTag</groups>
        </properties>
    </profile>
        <profile>
        <id>allTests</id>
        <properties>
            <groups>signUpTag,listingTag,loginTag</groups>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

The surefire plugin is defined under **build** section of the POM.xml

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <!--                   ***********************************************************************     -->
            <!--                                ***OPTION 2:: Configure groups , as below & remember to disable Option1 ***-->
            <!--                   ***********************************************************************     -->
            <!--                                <configuration>-->
            <!--                                        <groups>smokeTag</groups>-->
            <!--                                </configuration>-->
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When test are run using maven command, its skipping listing tests (when ran indivisually or as part of allTests profile)
I tried to create new test class & noticed that- its only running Signup tests & login tests

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

POM.xml details:

Comment: [First do not use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/296328) second upgrade your maven-surefire-plugin version to at least 2.22.2 or higher (3.0.0-M4 best from my POV). Also all the profiles are not needed because surefire supports that group tag...  https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved after removing, all of Juni4 dependencies from the project & after correcting imports to modern Junit5 Jupiter imports,

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
```

instead of having import conflicts

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
```